# Radix sort in singly-linked list C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, radix-sort

I'm trying to do a Radix sort in a Linked list class. I found radix sort algorithm for array and am trying to change it to work with my linked list. However, I'm a bit struggling. The code I'm trying to change is taken from http://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-10.php I tested the code with an array and it worked. Does anybody have any ideas how to make radix sort work in a linked list?

//abstract class

```
abstract class DataList
{
    protected int length;
    public int Length { get { return length; } }
    public abstract double Head();
    public abstract double Next();
    public abstract void Swap(int a, int b);
    public void Print(int n)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", Head());
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            Console.Write("{0} ", Next());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

//linked list class

```
class LinkedList : DataList
{
    class MyLinkedListNode
    {
        public MyLinkedListNode nextNode { get; set; }
        public int data { get; set; }
        public MyLinkedListNode(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public MyLinkedListNode()
        {
            this.data = 0;
        }
    }
    MyLinkedListNode headNode;
    MyLinkedListNode prevNode;
    MyLinkedListNode currentNode;
    public LinkedList(int n, int min, int max)
    {
        length = n;
        Random rand = new Random();
        headNode = new MyLinkedListNode(rand.Next(min, max));
        currentNode = headNode;
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            prevNode = currentNode;
            currentNode.nextNode = new MyLinkedListNode(rand.Next(min, max));
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
        currentNode.nextNode = null;
    }
    public LinkedList()
    {
        headNode = new MyLinkedListNode();
        currentNode = headNode;
    }
    public override double Head()
    {
        currentNode = headNode;
        prevNode = null;
        return currentNode.data;
    }
    public override double Next()
    {
        prevNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        return currentNode.data;
    }
    public override void Swap(int a, int b)
    {
        prevNode.data = a;
        currentNode.data = b;
    }
```

//my radix sort

```
    public void radixSort()
    {
        int j = 0;
        LinkedList tmp = new LinkedList();
        for (int shift = 31; shift > -1; --shift)
        {
            //I try to go trough old list
            MyLinkedListNode current = headNode;
            while (current != null)
            {
                bool move = (current.data << shift) >= 0;
//I found this expression somewhere and I'm trying to use it to form a new Linked list (tmp)
                if (shift == 0 ? !move : move)
                    ;
                else
                {
                    if (tmp.headNode == null)
                        tmp.headNode = currentNode;
                    else
                    {
                        tmp.currentNode.nextNode = current;
//infinite loop happens on the commented line
                        //tmp.currentNode = tmp.currentNode.nextNode; 
                        j++;
                    }
                current = current.nextNode;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the C# radix sort example, you need an array of ten lists. Move nodes from the original list into the ten lists, appending a node with least signfificant digit == '0' into array_of_lists[0], '1' into array_of_list[1], and so on. After the original list is emptied, then concatenate the array of lists back into the original list and repeat for the next to least significant digit. Repeat the process until all the digits are handled.

You could use a larger base, such as base 16, where you would use an array of 16 lists. You can then select each "digit" using a shift and an `and` .